# SetBufferSize from ubuntu. C#

Tags: c#, console, console-application

need to programmatically clear console history.
wanted to use cpnsole.clear () + setbuffersize () for this, but the latter is not supported on my system. Is it possible to clean up the console somehow differently?

error message:

```
Program.cs (28,21): warning CA1416: This challenge site is available on all platforms. "Console.SetBufferSize (int, int)" is only supported on 'windows'. [paint / paint.csproj]
```

is it possible to do this without removing the re-create console/

last time I was offered to do so, but it seems to me that this is the worst idea